# Sharing non-singleton state between controllers ( Angular Architecture )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my current company we are working on a very large angular application. One of the points of constant contention is to figure out what is the best way to share non-singleton state between controllers. In the ideal scenario, where the controllers share a state which happens to be a singleton we can model that state as a `service` and communicate between those `controllers` using this `service`, by `inject`ing it.

But we want to have multiple instances of this hierarchy, which means that having a singleton will not help. What we need is a context based singleton which can also be injectable.

We are currently planning to do it through the directive hierarchy where the topmost directive's controllers manages state and then all the lower directives `require` this controller ( directive controllers for directive to directive communication! ) and call functions on it . The problem with doing it this way is that the required controller is only accessible in the link function of the directives ( which isnt bad, but since most things would happen with this state, it will become harder to test. ! Link functions are harder to test than Controllers. You can directly inject controllers and test them. ) .

I am sure there are others out there who might have faced a similar scenario and come up with an agreeable solution!

Consider a hierarchy like this ( for example ) for better understanding:

```
<post>
    <header></header>
    <button-array></button-array>
    <editor></editor>
    <footer></footer>
</post>
<post>
    <header></header>
    <button-array></button-array>
    <editor></editor>
    <footer></footer>
</post>
```

....n posts each m level deep..

The example here is a trivial one, with just going 1 level deep in the DOM. Consider that in the application we have 4-5 level deep directives. We went down the isolate scope route and passing the values that are needed into the child directives. That worked but it felt wrong mostly because if a directive at level 5 needed something - all the directives in between had to marshall that data ( and expose a scope variable that didn't do anything but pass this value along to the next level! That seems very brittle ) .

If you have a good architectural eye for how to solve this - let us know. If you have any suggestions about what works or what wont - that would be great as well. If you know of relative merits and demerits of the different approaches used to solve this - that would be great as well.

Comment: I don't get the "passing down" issue: if `post` had an isolate scope and `header` etc. would be created by `post` (via template e.g.), then they wouldn't (read shouldn't) have an isolate scope themselves. So there is no need pass values. You would have to pass values needed by `header` to `post`, but that's natural and the number of values should be limited. Otherwise the design is flawed.

Comment: @zeroflagL So how would you share a single state object  between `post`  `header` , `button-array` and all the inner child directives ? What I was trying to say there is that we have gone the route of all having isolate scopes and that did not work out well because we had a list of attributes for each directive that was humungous.

Comment: But that's the point. The fact that this design (all isolate scopes) is difficult to handle could be a hint that it may not be the optimal solution. Without isolate scopes this question would be moot, or am I wrong?

Comment: When you say you are injecting the `service` you mean extending it in the `controller`? (i.e. `.controller(['someservice',function(someservice) {`)

Comment: @zeroflagL Nope. The question is how do you solve sharing state between a set of directives - without scope inheritance and without isolate scope.

Comment: @Malkus Yes. Basically injecting the stateObject as a service and calling operations on it ( in all the directives responsible! ).

Comment: I believe using the directive's controller hierarchy is indeed the best solution here. It may become harder to test but that's normal since you are basically creating a dependency, and like all dependencies, they depend on something to work :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm thinking about this correctly, the `<post>` elements in your example have some state objects associated with them, and they need to pass that down to `<header>` and so forth.

I approach this by attaching objects to scope at the html level. So `<post item="items[0]">`, and then the post template has in it `<header item="item">` and so forth. With isolate scope = type, changes propagate up and down the DOM tree since it's just one javascript object that's holding the data in it.

You could also use the directive controller hierarchy, but that means things like `<button-array>` are kind of hard-wired in where they appear in templates (and if you push down or pull up a child directive in terms of where it appears in the DOM hierarchy of the overall repeated object, that breaks things), whereas directly passing state into each item works okay.

I only do this with what I'd call 'model state' - stuff that you'd maybe eventually post to a server somewhere. Post title and content, tags, etc. View state (expand-collapse of objects) is handled internally to a component and used to detect the bounds of a component (if two components are tightly-bound enough to need access to each others' view state, then they're actually one component).